# I accidentally unbound my c-key in my macOS terminal when enabling autofill. How do I restore it?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, configuration, keyboard

So I was looking into how to enable mac terminal auto complete and stumbled upon solutions involving .inputrc. However, I must have messed up some input along the way, because now my c key doesn't work while in the terminal. Whenever I press it my terminal does a quick flash of disapproval and nothing else happens. Also, for some reason, upper case C still works just fine.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

For what it's worth: the auto complete works like a charm....

I've been searching for a way to factory reset my bindings, but to no avail.
Unfortunately I'm so new to messing with the terminal that I don't really now where to start or what to look for :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Remove the `.inputrc` file and restart Terminal.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go ask over there instead!